# insert integers with zeros in position after decimal point as a string to sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I want to store I string in sqlite table field, which looks like an integer.
The definition of the field in sqlite:

"time string"

For example for the value "126.70", I want that it is stored as a complete string, but I see in the database "126.7", so the last zero is cut of(as by integers)

here is my code:

```
    String time = "126.70";
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("time", time);
    db.replace(TABLE, null, cv);
```

How to avoid such behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string` is not an sqlite column type so the defaults apply. Use `text` instead:

```
sqlite> create table a(b text, c real);
sqlite> insert into a values("123.10", "123.10");
sqlite> select * from a;
123.10|123.1
```